# jquery accordion prevent style from being added

Tags: jquery, html, css, accordion

I am using jquery accordion plugin and all works great except that my submenu items may be variable, some could have 2 entries, other 4.  so the size of the submenu varies,  somewhere in the code I am seeing this style getting added to my accordion, any ideas how to prevent it, so that height is auto?

the unwanted style:

```
 style="display: block; height: 66px;"
```

jquery:

```
  $( ".leftMenu" ).accordion({
   active: false,
   collapsible: true,
   });
```

the php

```
            echo " <div class='leftMenu'> ";
                    echo "<h3>" . $topLevel[$k] . "</h3>";
                    echo "<div class='subMenu'>";
                    foreach ($_SESSION[ 'adminCreds'][ 'permissions'][$k] as $kk => $vv)
                    {
                            echo "<li class='menu' id='" . $kk . "'>" . $menu[$kk] . "</li>";
                    }
                    echo "</div>
            </div>";
```

notes .menu,leftMenu,li have no height attributes. if i set height to 0 on .menu, the style height becomes 33px;

plugin i am using:

[accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/)

Comment: Can you post a link of the plugin you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your markup I'm guessing you are using [Jquery UI Accordion](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-heightStyle)

You can set the height to auto like so:

```
$( ".leftMenu" ).accordion({ 
    heightStyle: "content"
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3Lk3s/)